# 'timestampadd' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to convert a 6 digit date into a regular looking date.

Currently we have this in the DB:

```
734562
734776
734837
```

Here's what I am trying:

```
select 



                    timestampadd(
                                    sql_tsi_day
                                    ,rbaging.billing_period_end
                                    ,cast('0001-01-01' as sql_timestamp)
                                )
                    -1,*


 from 

[kslap208].[c021]..RB_Resident_Aging  rbaging
```

the error i'm getting is:

```
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 5
'timestampadd' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

how do i convert this field into a regular date field?

Comment: Why would you think timestampadd is a valid SQL Server function?

Comment: what are those `int` values supposed to be once they are dates?

Comment: @bluefeet thats the number of days that have passed since 01/01/0001

Comment: You need the equivalent of `DATEADD(D, Field, '0001-01-01')`, but first you'll need to shift your date to a more reasonable base, like 1900-01-01.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades you can take that one up with the idiots who invented pervasive sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the remote source is an integer, or can be cast to one, I believe this should do it:

```
 SELECT DATEADD(DD, Field - 730000, '2001-01-01')
```

Comment: sorry idont understand why 2001 instead of 0001?

Comment: Because on MS SQL 2K8, '0001-01-01' is not a valid date.  Bumping it up by an even 2,000 years makes the math simple.  Hmm, too simple, I'm afraid, I didn't account for leap years!  You'll need to calibrate it slightly, to about 730,500.  Simplest would be to test a couple of dates and adjust until you're getting the right result.

Comment: by the way do you know if its possible to create indexed views on linked data sources???

Comment: No, I don't believe so.  The limits on indexing views are pretty strict.  You could maintain a local copy of the data, and index that.  Or you could use `OPENQUERY` to force your filtering to happen on the far side, if there are indices there that you can use.