# how to replace overflows with NULL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

**how do i replace an invalid datetime with null?**

I am doing some operations on an `INT` column that is actually a date representation:

```
select 


DATEADD(DD, rbaging.billing_period_end - 693594, '1900-01-01'),
DATEADD(DD, rbaging.billing_period_apply - 693594, '1900-01-01'),

*


 from 

[kslap208].[c021]..RB_Resident_Aging  rbaging

join
[kslap208].[c021]..PA_Profile_BASE_1119 pro
on rbaging.bill_to_profile_id=pro.profile_id   --4242

join 
[kslap208].[c021]..PA_Admit_Det_BASE_10 unit
on unit.profile_id=rbaging.bill_to_profile_id
```

the `rbaging` table as integer fields that are supposed to be dates. here's a sample:

```
734562
734776
734837
```

the documentation states to convert the INT to date this way:

[image]

when running my sql statement above, i am getting:

```
Msg 517, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused overflow.
```

**how do i replace an invalid datetime with null?**

Comment: Why are you adding the days to 1900 instead of 0001? `SELECT DATEADD(DAY,734562,CAST('00010101' AS DATE))` works fine and returns `2012-03-01`

Comment: @MartinSmith in sql server 0001 is not valid

Comment: Yes it is (with newer datatypes). See edit to previous comment.

Comment: @MartinSmith I believe they are using a linked server to a database that does not have a `date` datatype --- see previous question -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429886/timestampadd-is-not-a-recognized-built-in-function-name  -- and my deleted answer/comments

Comment: @MartinSmith indeed, bluefeet is correct. that is why the question is specifically about how to convert overflow into NULL

Comment: `select DATEDIFF(DAY,'00010101','99991231')` is `3652058` so that's the largest integer that won't cause an overflow. Sounds like the data is nonsense though if you have that kind of value in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
case when (rbaging.billing_period_end - 693594)>1
then DATEADD(DD, rbaging.billing_period_end - 693594, '1900-01-01')
else '' end,

case when (rbaging.billing_period_apply - 693594)>1
then DATEADD(DD, rbaging.billing_period_apply - 693594, '1900-01-01')
else ''
end
```

works like a charm!